# Alternatives to Google Directions API

Tags: api, google-maps, routes, maps

Which is the best alternative (if any) to the ***Google Directions API***?

Preferrably, it should be some solution I can host, but I can consider to use an online service less restritive than Google API. *These are the limits for Google Directions Business:*

> Google Maps API for Business customers may query up to 100,000
>   directions requests per day, with up to 23 waypoints allowed in each
>   request.

**UPDATE**

Besides these limitations, which can be negotiated with Google, I would like to have an alternative because it's a good pratice don't put all eggs in one basket :)

In *the absence of somebody with a opinion strong enough to share*, these two services seem to be good choices:

- [Here Maps](http://www.here.com/)
- MapLink

Comment: Hi, downvoter, how about putting a comment on which problem did you saw on how I've formulated my question? I've done my research, and I've found zero viable alternatives, if you know ONE, please let me know.

Comment: Do you really think somebody would downvote *instead of* answer your question? The ability to judge the quality of your question - and, very specifically, how it violates [our question guidelines](/help/on-topic) - is in no way related to our ability to provide the information you seek.

Comment: @tripleee I can say now, in 2019, no, I don't think so. But again, back in 2015, maybe the answer was "yes". And thanks, this is actually an useful feedback that could be used to improve my question back there, hope that it throw some light of advice for other people who are reading this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These restrictions are usually placed to discourage misuse of services. However, if you need more quota it can be easily requested through [Google for Work Support Portal](https://google.secure.force.com/). There are no restrictions to how much quota you can request but you should take the appropriate measures to ensure it's proper usage. For example: Implementing [Exponential Back-off Algorithm](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff) to avoid hitting frequent rate-limit errors.

Answer (score 7):

One replacement for Google Directions API is [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper). It is a routing engine written in Java which uses OpenStreetMap data. It is Open Source, extremly fast and suitable for self-hosting. You have two options:

- Embbeded in your Java application
- Self-hosted as a web service with access via API

You can try it online: https://graphhopper.com/maps/

If you want to know more about embedding GraphHopper in your application you can visit my article at https://bmehner.github.io/graphhopper/

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure : I work for TomTom.

Have you considered our [TomTom Maps APIs](https://developer.tomtom.com).

We believe we are the best alternative for Maps APIs. To get directions you can use the [Routing API](https://developer.tomtom.com/routing-api/routing-api-documentation-routing/calculate-route)'s instructions type parameter :

**instructionsType** *string*.
    If specified, guidance instructions will be returned (if available). Possible values are:

1. coded: Returns raw instruction data without human-readable messages.
2. text: Returns raw instructions data with human-readable messages in plain text.
3. tagged: Returns raw instruction data with tagged human-readable messages to permit formatting.

You can request a free API KEY (No credit card required and no locked-in contracts) and TomTom will allow you to mix and match APIs from different providers.

Check out our [tutorials](https://developer.tomtom.com/tutorials) for JS.